# Elements Auto Grid.Row and Grid.Column

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, grid

I have a MainPage.xaml code:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="GridTest.MainPage">
    <ScrollView>
            <Grid x:Name="test" >
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="100" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="100" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Button Text="Hello, world" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"></Button>
                <Button Text="Hello, world" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"></Button>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollView>
        
</ContentPage>
```

Is it possible to set Button Parameters Grid.Row and Grid.Column automatically? Not manually.

Comment: No.  How would that even work?  If you don't assign an explicit value it will default to 0

Comment: @Jason, I want the elements to be distributed on the grid themselves. None of this can be realized in any way?

Comment: No.  You can try using a CollectionView if you want a simple left-right top-bottom distribution

Comment: As Jason saide, the `Grid` will not arrange the child views automatically. For this feature, try to set use the [CollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/layout#vertical-grid) instead. Set the **ItemsLayout** to **GridItemsLayout** to display the items in a vertical grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to set Button Parameters Grid.Row and Grid.Column automatically? Not manually

As Jason saide, the `Grid` will not arrange the child views automatically. The value of `Grid.Row` or `Grid.Column` will be **0** by default.

For this feature, try to set use the [CollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/layout#vertical-grid) instead. Set the **ItemsLayout** to **GridItemsLayout** to display the items in a vertical grid.

Check the code:

```
<CollectionView>
    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" Span="2"/>
    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
    <CollectionView.ItemsSource>
        <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
            <x:String>Hello, world</x:String>
            <x:String>Hello, world</x:String>
            <x:String>Hello, world</x:String>
            <x:String>Hello, world</x:String>
        </x:Array>
    </CollectionView.ItemsSource>
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout>
                <Button Text="{Binding }"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```